# How to send e-mails with excel template as pdf attachment?

Tags: excel, pdf

I have a list of e-mails in an Excel document, I am using Office 365. Suppose we have the following information about each recipient :

1. Name
2. E-mail
3. Price

I have an invoice template that I want to fill in with the previous information and create one invoice by recipient. I then want to create a pdf. Finally, I want to create an e-mail with pdf as attachment.

You can suppose that I also have an e-mail template to fill-in with the recipient's information.

Is there a way to do this without using VBA ? For example, can I do this with Merge Mail ?

If not, how can I do this with a simple VBA code ?

Thank you!

Comment: _Simple_ is relative. For an experienced VBA programmer, this is 'simple', and he can maybe do it in his lunch break. For a beginner with no VBA experience, the learning curve might require a week of effort. Either way, it will require some 50 to 100 lines of custom code.

Comment: I have no VBA experience, but I do code on a semi-regular basis. Also, I do believe this worth the effort, since the person sending the e-mails at the moment does all of this by hand. I believe this would save her a lot of time in the long run.